# Different sorting algorithms fail on large arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, processing

I am trying to sort the arrays using different algorithms. When I run the application with small number of arrays, it works and produces the results. When the arrays are larger than: 131072, it stops responding.

What can be the reason? Is there anything wrong with this code?

This is my function:

```
boolean runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url, String out, Sort sort) {
  PrintWriter filename;
  boolean tobeReturned = true;
  String beforeSorting = "";
  String afterSorting = "";

  long startTime;
  double timeTaken;
  try {
    filename = createWriter(out);

    for(File directory : new File(url).listFiles()){
      File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();     
      filename.println("Number of Records: \t" + directory.getName());

      for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        text = loadStrings(file);
        number = int(text);
        if (isSorted(number)) { beforeSorting = "Sorted";} else { beforeSorting = "NOT Sorted"; };

        startTime = startTime();       
        sort.sortInteger(number);        
        timeTaken = stopTime(startTime);

        if (isSorted(number)) { afterSorting = "Sorted"; } else { afterSorting = "NOT Sorted"; };

        filename.println("File Set " + file.getName() + ": \t\t" + beforeSorting + ": \t" + afterSorting + ": \t" + timeTaken);
        timeTaken = 0;
      }
      filename.println("\n");
    }
    filename.flush();
    filename.close();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    tobeReturned = false;
  }
  return tobeReturned;
}
```

**Interface:**

```
interface Sort{
   public int[] sortInteger(int[] input);
}
```

**One of the sorting class (Insertion)**

```
class Insertion implements Sort{

  Insertion() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    int i, j, tobeSorted;
    for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
      tobeSorted = input[i];
      j = i;
      while (j > 0 && input[j - 1] > tobeSorted) {
        input[j] = input[j - 1];
        j--;
      }
      input[j] = tobeSorted;
    }
    //println(input);
    return input;
  }
}
```

Numbers folders:

[image]

Files:

[image]

Records:

[image]

Result of insertion sort:

[image]

Result of merge sort:

[image]

******UPDATE******

**Full Simplified Processing Code**

```
import java.util.*; 

long a = 9; // total loop, 9 means = 65536, 10 means = 131072 ...
long b = 2;  // multiplier, 2 means = 512,1024,2048...
long c = 512; // starting number
long d = 5; // times random text file

String url; 

Insertion insertion;
Merge merge;
Bubble bubble;
Shell shell;
QuickSort quickSort;

void setup() {
  url = sketchPath("_numbers/");  

  insertion = new Insertion();
  merge = new Merge();
  bubble = new Bubble();
  shell = new Shell();
  quickSort = new QuickSort();

  generateFiles(a,b,c,d);

  boolean runSortTest = false;
    runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/a_insertion.txt", insertion);
    runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/b_merge.txt", merge);
    runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/c_bubble.txt", bubble);
    runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/d_shell.txt", shell);
    runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/e_quickSort.txt", quickSort);

    if(runSortTest){
      println("Done");
    }else{
      println("Error");
    }

}

boolean generateFiles(long totalLoop, long multiplier, long power, long fileNumber){
  PrintWriter pw;
  //int orderCount = 1;
  int count = 1;
  //boolean tobeReturned = true;
  try {
    for (int i = 1; i < totalLoop; i = i+1) {   
      for (int j = 1; j < fileNumber+1; j = j+1) {
        pw = createWriter("/_numbers/" + power + "/" + count + ".txt"); 

        for (int k = 0; k < power; k = k+1) { 
          pw.println(randomNumber(0, power));
          //pw.write(int(randomNumber(0, power)) + "\t");
        }
        count++;

        pw.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
        pw.close(); // Finishes the file
      }
      count = 1;
      //orderCount++;
      power *= multiplier; 
    }
    //orderCount = 1;
    return  true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}

long randomNumber(long min, long max){
  long randomN = (long)random(min,(max + 1));
  return randomN;
}

//####################################################################################################
//## Runs the test and produces a log file for each algorithms
//####################################################################################################

boolean runTest(String url, String out, Sort sort) {
  PrintWriter filename;
  boolean tobeReturned = true;
  String beforeSorting = "";
  String afterSorting = "";

  long startTime;
  double timeTaken;
  try {
    filename = createWriter(out);

    for(File directory : new File(url).listFiles()){
      File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();     
      filename.println("Number of Records: \t" + directory.getName());

      for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        String[] text; int[] number;
        text = loadStrings(file);
        number = int(text);
        if (isSorted(number)) { beforeSorting = "Sorted";} else { beforeSorting = "NOT Sorted"; };

        startTime = startTime();       
        sort.sortInteger(number);        
        timeTaken = stopTime(startTime);

        if (isSorted(number)) { afterSorting = "Sorted"; } else { afterSorting = "NOT Sorted"; };

        filename.println("File Set " + file.getName() + ": \t\t" + beforeSorting + ": \t" + afterSorting + ": \t" + timeTaken);
        timeTaken = 0;
        Arrays.fill(text, null);
        number = null;
      }
      filename.println("\n");
    }
    filename.flush();
    filename.close();

  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    tobeReturned = false;
  }
  return tobeReturned;
}



boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i ++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

//####################################################################################################
//## Time comparison
//####################################################################################################

long startTime() {
  return System.nanoTime();
}

double stopTime(long startTime) {
  double finalTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000000.0;
  return finalTime;
}

/*

Interface
 # Last update: 20 October 2015 
*/

interface Sort{
   public int[] sortInteger(int[] input);
}

/*

Insertion class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 25 October 2015
*/


class Insertion implements Sort{

  Insertion() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    int i, j, tobeSorted;
    for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
      tobeSorted = input[i];
      j = i;
      while (j > 0 && input[j - 1] > tobeSorted) {
        input[j] = input[j - 1];
        j--;
      }
      input[j] = tobeSorted;
    }
    //println(input);
    return input;
  }
}

/*

Merge class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 25 October 2015 
*/


class Merge implements Sort{

  Merge() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    if (input.length > 1) {
      // split array into two halves
      int[] left = leftHalf(input);
      int[] right = rightHalf(input);

      // recursively sort the two halves
      sortInteger(left);
      sortInteger(right);

      // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
      merge(input, left, right);
    }
    return input;
  }

  // Returns the first half of the given array.
  int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
    int size1 = array.length / 2;
    int[] left = new int[size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
      left[i] = array[i];
    }
    return left;
  }

  // Returns the second half of the given array.
  int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
    int size1 = array.length / 2;
    int size2 = array.length - size1;
    int[] right = new int[size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
      right[i] = array[i + size1];
    }
    return right;
  }

  void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
    int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
    int i2 = 0;   // index into right array

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length &&
        left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
        result[i] = left[i1];    // take from left
        i1++;
      } else {
        result[i] = right[i2];   // take from right
        i2++;
      }
    }
  }

}

/*

 Bubble class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 25 October 2015
 */


class Bubble implements Sort {

  Bubble() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) {
      swapped = false;
      j++;
      for (int i = 0; i < input.length - j; i++) {                                       
        if (input[i] > input[i + 1]) {                          
          tmp = input[i];
          input[i] = input[i + 1];
          input[i + 1] = tmp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}

/*

 Shell class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 25 October 2015 
 */


class Shell implements Sort {

  Shell() {
  }

  int[] sequence = {59724292, 26544130, 11797391, 5243258, 2330349, 1035711, 460316, 204585, 90927, 40412, 17961, 7983, 3548, 1577, 701, 301, 132, 57, 23, 10, 4, 1};
  /*
  int number = 701;
   for(int i=0; i<15; i++){    
   int newN = int(number*2.25);
   println(number);
   number =  newN;    
   }
   */

  int[] sortInteger (int[] input) {
    int size = input.length;
    int i, j, temp;
    for ( int s : sequence ) {
      i = s;
      while ( i < size ) {
        temp = input[i];
        j = i-s;
        while ( j >= 0 && input[j] > temp ) {
          input[j + s] = input[j];
          j -= s;
        }
        input[j + s] = temp;
        i ++;
      }
    }
    return input;
  }

}

/*

 QuickSort class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 26 October 2015 
 */


class QuickSort implements Sort {

  QuickSort() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    quickSort(input, 0, input.length-1) ;
    return  input;
  }

  public void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
  {
    int i = low, j = high;
    int temp;
    int pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2];

    /** partition **/
    while (i <= j) 
    {
      while (arr[i] < pivot)
        i++;
      while (arr[j] > pivot)
        j--;
      if (i <= j) 
      {
        /** swap **/
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;

        i++;
        j--;
      }
    }

    /** recursively sort lower half **/
    if (low < j)
      quickSort(arr, low, j);
    /** recursively sort upper half **/
    if (i < high)
      quickSort(arr, i, high);
  }
}
```

Comment: The amount of data you are sorting through array is overwhelming for the machine. Using arrays is not very good choice in this example. Just use more flexible data structure, for example linked list. Plus linked lists are thread safe.

Comment: Measure the time it takes to do a sort for the smaller ones (512-65536) and post them here. You might have a greater time complexity than you imagine.

Comment: @TheLaw Nothing wrong with using arrays here. `LinkedList` would not be a good choice here (in fact, it's very rarely a good choice). `LinkedList` is not thread-safe either.

Comment: @TheLaw It's perfectly possible to have a non thread safe linked list implementation.

Comment: @Kayaman Agree, although to be fair, he didn't specify a particular implementation of linked list.

Comment: I added the result of insertion and merge sort

Comment: @Michael No he didn't, yet he claimed that it would be thread-safe. If he had said "use the linked list from FooBar library, it's thread-safe" I wouldn't have corrected him on the thread safety issue. I would have corrected him on the other two points and added that it doesn't make sense to go for external resources just to get a linked list.

Comment: @emre22 What is your `timeTaken` units? Why do you sort all the files inside the folder separately? Why do you even have separate files instead of having one with 512 records, one with 1024 and so on?

Comment: The reason of having multiple text files in the folder is to get accurate result. If I had only 1 text file in each folder, the result might not be correct.  timeTaken variable is just doing a very basic calculation.

Comment: How about generating a message disclosing details of the `Exception e`? (Besides, I consider screen shots to present text output unreasonable)

Comment: you can check with `top` how your machine behaves during the execution of this program. The temporal complexity is huge ( `d * f * 2n * sorting`, where `d` is the number of directories, `f` the number of files, `n` the element in each file, `2` because you checked twice if the array is sorted and this can only be linear - I guess). Also I have concern about spatial complexity: try to set `text` and `number` to `null` after the inner `for` to clean up some memory. Anyway, with `top` you will see how your system resources react to the program.

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish I just tried quickly and it worked. I think this will solve my problem.

Comment: What happens if you add `e.printStackTrace()` inside your catch block? Right now you're ignoring any errors you get, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: Nothing happens, I dont get any error, the application stops responding

Comment: @emre22 I'd recommend running this in a debugger, or at least adding a bunch of print statements, so you can figure out exactly what the program is doing.

Comment: I run in a debugger but there is no error. I updated the question and added a simplified version of the full code. You can try and see.

Comment: Are you sure it stops responding and not just processing for a long time? Run it through the debugger and when it seems to have stopped responding press pause and see where it's at. If you're in Eclipse go to debug view and when you run it watch the thread. If it's really just stopping that thread's status will change.

Comment: I left it all night and it was exactly the same in the morning. I mean at least one of them should have finished. I will try running on eclipse when i go home.

Comment: @emre22, out of curiosity, do you still have problems? I read my suggestion helped you but now I see the discussion continued and I am curious if you still have problems, if the `null` trick was enough or if you find another way to make it worked.

Comment: Yes, I still have the same problem. I managed to sort 524288 x 10 random numbers. When I try anything above, my application freezes and i don`t get any error or warnings. I was going to create the same application on eclipse but I had no time. I guess that my problem might be the java settings on my computer. The memory usage doesn`t go higher than 400mb. I tried different ways to increase this but no luck. My PC has 32gb of ram. Anyway, I created this application for the college and I am not that bothered. I adjusted the application and wrote my report according to 262144 random numbers.

Comment: If you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the data you're trying to sort, I'll take a closer look at this.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I updated the question and added a Full Simplified Processing Code (At the bottom of the question). It creates the files and then sorts them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step to figuring this out is to **isolate the problem**. This is what we mean when we ask for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have to figure out exactly where the problem is happening. An easy way to do that is to add `println()` statements:

```
  boolean runSortTest = false;
  println("1");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/a_insertion.txt", insertion);
  println("2");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/b_merge.txt", merge);
  println("3");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/c_bubble.txt", bubble);
  println("4");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/d_shell.txt", shell);
  println("5");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/e_quickSort.txt", quickSort);
  println("6");
```

Doing this, we'll see that 1, 2, and 3 print out, but 4, 5, and 6 don't. That means you're getting stuck in the bubble sort somewhere. We can confirm that by commenting out the bubble sort and seeing what happens:

```
  boolean runSortTest = false;
  println("1");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/a_insertion.txt", insertion);
  println("2");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/b_merge.txt", merge);
  println("3");
  //runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/c_bubble.txt", bubble);
  println("4");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/d_shell.txt", shell);
  println("5");
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/e_quickSort.txt", quickSort);
  println("6");
```

Now, the program executes fine. So now we already know that the problem is with the bubble sort, so we can get rid of everything else:

```
import java.util.*; 

long a = 9; // total loop, 9 means = 65536, 10 means = 131072 ...
long b = 2;  // multiplier, 2 means = 512,1024,2048...
long c = 512; // starting number
long d = 5; // times random text file

String url; 

Bubble bubble;

void setup() {
  url = sketchPath("_numbers/");  

  bubble = new Bubble();
  generateFiles(a, b, c, d);

  boolean runSortTest = false;
  runSortTest = runTest(url, "_results/c_bubble.txt", bubble);

  if (runSortTest) {
    println("Done");
  } else {
    println("Error");
  }
}

boolean generateFiles(long totalLoop, long multiplier, long power, long fileNumber) {
  PrintWriter pw;
  //int orderCount = 1;
  int count = 1;
  //boolean tobeReturned = true;
  try {
    for (int i = 1; i < totalLoop; i = i+1) {   
      for (int j = 1; j < fileNumber+1; j = j+1) {
        pw = createWriter("/_numbers/" + power + "/" + count + ".txt"); 

        for (int k = 0; k < power; k = k+1) { 
          pw.println(randomNumber(0, power));
          //pw.write(int(randomNumber(0, power)) + "\t");
        }
        count++;

        pw.flush(); // Writes the remaining data to the file
        pw.close(); // Finishes the file
      }
      count = 1;
      //orderCount++;
      power *= multiplier;
    }
    //orderCount = 1;
    return  true;
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}

long randomNumber(long min, long max) {
  long randomN = (long)random(min, (max + 1));
  return randomN;
}

//####################################################################################################
//## Runs the test and produces a log file for each algorithms
//####################################################################################################

boolean runTest(String url, String out, Sort sort) {
  PrintWriter filename;
  boolean tobeReturned = true;
  String beforeSorting = "";
  String afterSorting = "";

  long startTime;
  double timeTaken;
  try {
    filename = createWriter(out);

    for (File directory : new File(url).listFiles()) {
      File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();     
      filename.println("Number of Records: \t" + directory.getName());

      for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        String[] text; 
        int[] number;
        text = loadStrings(file);
        number = int(text);
        if (isSorted(number)) { 
          beforeSorting = "Sorted";
        } else { 
          beforeSorting = "NOT Sorted";
        };

        startTime = startTime();       
        sort.sortInteger(number);        
        timeTaken = stopTime(startTime);

        if (isSorted(number)) { 
          afterSorting = "Sorted";
        } else { 
          afterSorting = "NOT Sorted";
        };

        filename.println("File Set " + file.getName() + ": \t\t" + beforeSorting + ": \t" + afterSorting + ": \t" + timeTaken);
        timeTaken = 0;
        Arrays.fill(text, null);
        number = null;
      }
      filename.println("\n");
    }
    filename.flush();
    filename.close();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    tobeReturned = false;
  }
  return tobeReturned;
}



boolean isSorted(int[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i ++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

//####################################################################################################
//## Time comparison
//####################################################################################################

long startTime() {
  return System.nanoTime();
}

double stopTime(long startTime) {
  double finalTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000000.0;
  return finalTime;
}

/*

 Interface
 # Last update: 20 October 2015 
 */

interface Sort {
  public int[] sortInteger(int[] input);
}


/*
 Bubble class, implements Sort interface
 # Last update: 25 October 2015
 */
class Bubble implements Sort {

  Bubble() {
  }

  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) {
      swapped = false;
      j++;
      for (int i = 0; i < input.length - j; i++) {                                       
        if (input[i] > input[i + 1]) {                          
          tmp = input[i];
          input[i] = input[i + 1];
          input[i + 1] = tmp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

This could probably be shortened even further, but the idea is this: **remove anything that doesn't directly have to do with the problem**.

Now that we've eliminated some of the extra information, we can take a closer look at your bubble sort. Again, `println()` statements are your best friend:

```
  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    
    println("input length: " + input.length);
```

Using this, you can see that it is indeed still running, since the following is printed out:

```
input length: 1024
input length: 1024
input length: 1024
input length: 1024
input length: 1024
input length: 16384
input length: 16384
input length: 16384
input length: 16384
input length: 16384
input length: 2048
input length: 2048
input length: 2048
input length: 2048
input length: 2048
input length: 32768
input length: 32768
input length: 32768
input length: 32768
input length: 32768
input length: 4096
input length: 4096
input length: 4096
input length: 4096
input length: 4096
input length: 512
input length: 512
input length: 512
input length: 512
input length: 512
input length: 65536
input length: 65536
input length: 65536
input length: 65536
input length: 65536
input length: 8192
input length: 8192
input length: 8192
input length: 8192
input length: 8192
Done
```

In fact: **this finishes fine**, you just have to give it a couple minutes. Here is the output I get in `c_bubble.txt`:

Number of Records:  1024

```
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.009598049335181713
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0011289309477433562
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0026859149802476168
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.002715847920626402
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0015163590433076024


Number of Records:  16384
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.38029658794403076
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.37928950786590576
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.3931492865085602
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.3918215036392212
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.38513386249542236


Number of Records:  2048
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0040453351102769375
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0041389851830899715
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.004071420058608055
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.004472961183637381
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0041146110743284225


Number of Records:  32768
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     1.6499463319778442
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     1.6393990516662598
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     1.628066897392273
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     1.6488127708435059
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     1.6586071252822876


Number of Records:  4096
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0184687077999115
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.018312623724341393
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.018741531297564507
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.01845288649201393
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.018356671556830406


Number of Records:  512
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     3.81015008315444E-4
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     3.322649863548577E-4
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     3.3953398815356195E-4
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     3.314100031275302E-4
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     3.42526996973902E-4


Number of Records:  65536
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     6.721750736236572
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     6.752647399902344
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     6.7578630447387695
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     6.696788787841797
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     6.759160995483398


Number of Records:  8192
File Set 1.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.08915259689092636
File Set 2.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.09149085730314255
File Set 3.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.0899868980050087
File Set 4.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.08892638236284256
File Set 5.txt:         NOT Sorted:     Sorted:     0.08631659299135208
```

Now that we know your bubble sort finishes, let's go back and see if the whole thing finishes. Yep, it does:

[image]

This finishes fine, and seems to provide results.

I would guess that you don't actually have a problem, but you were expecting the sketch to do something visual instead of just show you a gray box. But since you don't have a `draw()` function, you'll just see a gray box. If you don't want a window to pop up, try adding a call to `exit()` at the end of your `setup()` function.

If you still think it's not working, consider the following:

- Add more print statements so you can better see what's going on in your code.
- Check the output directory for files.
- Note that your program doesn't do anything visual since you don't have a `draw()` function, so all it does is show a gray box. **This doesn't mean your program is unresponsive!** It just means you haven't told it to do anything. Consider adding a call to `exit()` at the end of your `setup()` function.
- If all else fails, try to go through the above process to **isolate the problem**. Try to narrow it down to a few lines that don't do what you expect, not your entire sketch.

### Edit

You mentioned that you got similar results, and you only saw the problem when you increased your input size. **This is exactly what you should expect.**

Again, adding print statements is your best friend. Let's start with the insertion sort:

```
  int[] sortInteger(int[] input) {
    println("input length: " + input.length);
```

This will show you that your input length is 1,048,576. Since insertion sort is O(n^2), that means you'll have to do 1,048,576 ^ 2 comparisons. That's 1,099,511,627,776 comparisons! Assuming your computer could do 1,000 comparisons per second, **it would take 34 years for this algorithm to finish**.

(Your computer can probably do more than 1,000 comparisons per second. But if it could do 1 million comparisons per second, it would still take 12 days to complete. If it could do 1 billion comparisons per second, it would take 18 minutes, and that's just for a single run of one algorithm.)

To further investigate this, again, `println()` statements are your best friend. Try adding a `println()` statement that shows you the value of `i` in your insertion sort loop:

```
int i, j, tobeSorted;
    for (i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
      tobeSorted = input[i];
      j = i;
      while (j > 0 && input[j - 1] > tobeSorted) {
        input[j] = input[j - 1];
        j--;
      }
      input[j] = tobeSorted;
      
      println("i: " + i);
    }
```

As your program runs, you'll see this number going up. And even though computers are fast, it still takes a very long time to handle your entire input. This tells you that your program isn't hanging anywhere, it's just taking a long time to execute.

**This is the entire point of studying these algorithms.** Computers aren't magic calculators, and there are limits to the number of calculations they can do in a reasonable amount of time. This is why it matters whether your algorithm scales linearly or exponentially: does doubling your input size double the time it takes, or does it take exponentially longer?

If you *still* don't believe the results, keep trying to isolate the problem. Try to figure out exactly what your program is doing when you think it's "just sitting there". You should know exactly how many calculations your program needs to do, and then just print out how many calculations have been done so far. In other words: print out the number of times a loop should execute, and then print out the number of times the loop has executed so far. You'll see what a big number the first value is, and then how long it takes the second number to reach it.

### Edit 2

Here is a simplified version of your sketch that lets you more easily change the length of your input to get specific times for the different algorithms in a more "bite sized" way:

```
void setup() {
  int[] input = getInput(1000);

  int start = millis();
  bubbleSort(input);
  int elapsed = millis() - start;
  println("Elapsed: " + elapsed);
  exit();
}

int[] getInput(int n) {
  int[] input = new int[n];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    input[i] = (int)random(n);
  }

  return input;
}

int[] bubbleSort(int[] input) {

  boolean swapped = true;
  int j = 0;
  int tmp;
  while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - j; i++) {                                       
      if (input[i] > input[i + 1]) {                          
        tmp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[i + 1];
        input[i + 1] = tmp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return input;
}
```

Just change the value being passed into the `getInput()` function, and you'll be able to see how it affects the time it takes your algorithm to finish.

Here's bubble sort:

```
N: 1,000     Time: 7
N: 10,000    Time: 145
N: 100,000   Time: 14600
N: 1,000,000 Time: 1467533
```

So you see that multiplying your input size by 10 doesn't multiply your time by 10, **it multiplies it by 100**. This is because bubble sort is O(n^2), so the time it takes increases quadratically, not just linearly. If we tried to increase our N to 10,000,000, bubble sort would take about 40 hours!

Merge sort is much more forgiving, since it's O(n*log(n)):

```
N: 1,000      Time: 1
N: 10,000     Time: 5
N: 100,000    Time: 38
N: 1,000,000  Time: 221
N: 10,000,000 Time: 2202
```

That's the big lesson to learn here: bubble sort would take 40 hours to sort 10 million items, but merge sort only takes 2 seconds!

So the fact that large input takes a long time to sort is **exactly the point**. It's not a bug. Your program isn't hanging, it just takes a very long time to sort that many items. Try breaking your problem down into smaller bite-sized sketches like my example, that way you can more easily look closer at exactly what it's doing. Then add `println()` statements to see where your program is spending its time. **That's how you solve problems like the one you're having.**

### Edit 3

Now you mentioned that you're getting a "not responding" message in the task manager. Again, this is exactly what I would expect. You're telling Processing to do a lot of calculations, and while those calculations are running, the program will not be responsive. Large input might take hours (or days, or even longer!) to complete. So it doesn't at all surprise me that your program wouldn't complete overnight and the OS says it's unresponsive. This is where the idea of **threads** becomes useful, but that's an entirely separate can of worms.

If you're still having trouble, consider using my small example to repeat the problem, then you'll be able to ask a more specific question (in a new question, not in an edit to this one). Make sure to include which exact sorting algorithm you're using, what value of N you're using, and whether the program is still executing or has an error been thrown. Again, `println()` statements are your best friend.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for spending time on this question. I have already done exactly what you described above, and i had the same problem with the bubble sort, that is when i tried to test one by one. My final version displays a visual output on the screen. The above codes work when the array size is small. I get the problem when array size is increased. Can you please change the values of the variables as below and repeat the test. `long a = 14; long d = 10`;

Comment: @emre22 I've edited my answer to include an explanation on that, but that's exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @emre22 And I've included another edit to further explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I wish I explained my problem properly. When i run the test with large number of arrays, my processing IDE did not respond and I had the warning "Not Responding" in the Task Manager against the application. At that point Processing did not print anything. I left the application running all night but it was exactly the same in the morning. As you said, if i performed only one sorting algorithm at a time using `println`, I would solve the problem. Your explanation makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: @emre22 I've included another edit, but again, that's exactly what I would expect to happen.